# Pop!OS 20.04 - Glitched screen instead of login screen

Tags: boot, display

I am running Pop!OS 20.04, on an Asus Tuf FX505DU with an Nvidia 1660TI, and sometimes when I boot up the OS, instead of the login screen I get a glitched screen (horizontal bars of pixels of different colours) and it keeps turning on and off for a bit.

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, I can enter TTY and login, I can run

```
sudo systemctl restart gdm
```

and everything returns to normal.
I suppose it happens because GDM gets executed before the nvidia driver is loaded?
Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Do you mean an Nvidia 1070Ti? Or the 1660Ti?

Comment: Oh, wait, it's 1660TI. I mistyped that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by simply reinstalling GDM.
Originally, I thought it's a graphical driver loading issue, but apparently this did the trick.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gdm3 pop-desktop gnome-shell
sudo systemctl reboot
```

**Edit:** Here's the link to System76's article that I used: https://support.system76.com/articles/login-loop-pop/